# Convert vector<string> to char** for use in execvp

Tags: c++

I have a vector named tokens that holds the command in tokens[0] and args as the rest of the vector. I am trying to convert the vector so I can make the call to `execvp(args[0], args);` Currently args[0] and args just print as memory addresses.

```
  char **args = (char**)malloc(tokens.size() * sizeof(string));
  char *arg;

  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
  {
    arg = &tokens[i][0];
    args[i] = arg;
  }
```

Comment: `"just print as memory addresses"` - Show the code to your print statement.

Comment: cout << args[0] << "\n";
  cout << args;

Comment: `args` is not a string (it's an array of strings), hence cout will print its address value.  I'm not sure why `args[0]` wouldn't print a valid string.

Comment: yes, i am also confused. args[0] prints as the same address as args

Comment: `sizeof(string)` doesnt do anything useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the answer lies with adding the NULL terminator to the end of the vector so that execvp knows where to end pvec.data(); This is thanks to Fatih above.

````
  std::vector<char*> pvec(tokens.size());
  std::transform(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), pvec.begin(), [](auto& str) {
    return &str[0];
  });
  pvec.push_back(NULL);
  pvec.data();

  pid = fork();
  // if we enter child process
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    if (execvp(pvec.data()[0], pvec.data()) == -1)
    {
      printf("right here officer\n");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }```
````

Comment: `pvec.data();` is a no-op, it is not doing anything

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to resort to `malloc` to perform this since you are already using vectors of strings.

You could just create a `std::vector<char*>` before calling `execvp`:

```
std::vector<char*> pvec(tokens.size());
std::transform(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), pvec.begin(), [](auto& str) {
  return &str[0];
});
pvec.data(); // This is a char**, pass it to `execvp`
```

Comment: @Alejandro, awesome! You can also mark it as so by clicking the little tick below the up/down arrows :)

Comment: Actually this only works when execvp is only given the first parameter pvec.data()[0].

When I make this call execvp(pvec.data()[0], pvec.data()), programs with arguments do not work. In my case I am running /usr/bin/xterm -bg green.

*note -  I don't have enough reputation to upvote your post unfortunately.

Comment: That might have something to do with how you construct `tokens`. This just converts that vector to a vector of `char*`s. What do you have in `tokens` for `/usr/bin/xterm -bg green`?